# UnCaughtSyntax Error: Unexpected Token Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am getting the `UncaughtSyntax Error: Unexpected Token` in my code.

This is my javascript that I am using

```
function showTab(tabId){
        window.alert(tabId);
        var allTabs = ["materials_1","materials_2", "materials_3" , "materials_4", "materials_5"];
        for tab in allTabs{
            document.getElementById(tab).style.display = "none";
        }
        document.getElementById(tabId).style.display = "";
    }
```

This is the part of HTML code which I need to run:

```
<a class="btn submission-btn" onclick="showTab("materials_2")" role="button">NEXT</a>
```

I added the `window.alert()` box just to see if it goes inside the function.
Unfortunately, this piece of code is not working. Please help.

On debugging the code, it shows that the error is after this part of the code:

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-4"></div>
                <a class="btn submission-btn" onclick="showTab("materials_2")" role="button">NEXT</a>
            </div>
```

Comment: Use debugging console of chrome or another browser to debug correct your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are **`missing ()`** in for loop also the parameter should be enclosed in **`''`**

```
for( tab in allTabs){
```

**DEMO**

```js
function showTab(tabId){
        window.alert(tabId);
        var allTabs = ["materials_1","materials_2", "materials_3" , "materials_4", "materials_5"];
        for( tab in allTabs){
            document.getElementById(tab).style.display = "none";
        }
        document.getElementById(tabId).style.display = "";
 };
```

```html
<a class="btn submission-btn" onclick="showTab('materials_2')" role="button">NEXT</a>
```

Comment: what do you mean? did you check the demo

Comment: If you run the script that you provided, I get another error called cannot read property 'style' of null

Comment: obviously because there are no elements named material_2 in your HTML

Comment: There are. The HTML file i big, so I did not paste the whole of the file.

Comment: So how do you expect my code to work without having the whole HTML? i just resolved your main issue

Comment: Sorry about that.
When I run the snippet in my own code, it still gives me the same error. I just checked my spellings everywhere, and they all are correct